# How Visual Studio checkes that SharePoint has been installed on my local PC?

Tags: 2013, solution-package, visual-studio-2012

I want to build wsp file for SharePoint 2013, but it is not installed on my local PC. What should I do to make this thing possible? I guess that I need to tell Visual Studio somehow that SharePoint has been installed. I'm going to copy all required dll from SharePoint to the project. Will it work?

Comment: Why can you not install SharePoint on to a local Dev Machine using Virtualisation technology?

Comment: Could you please provide little bit more information about Virtualisation technology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio checks certain registry keys to make sure Sharepoint is installed. This URL describes where these keys are located: http://sharepointmalaya.blogspot.com/2009/07/how-to-check-if-moss-or-wss-is.html

You can build Sharepoint solutions without having to install Sharepoint, but you cannot debug. Remember to copy all the Sharepoint Binaries from a valid installations Bin folder.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to debug remote SharePoint web parts using Remote Debug Monitor?

Comment: Never tried it and as far as I remember there were limitations. Try firing up VS Remote debugger and attach to al lthe w3wp.exe processes to see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Sure so you have software such as Microsoft's Hyper V and VMWare's Workstation product which allow you to install and run machines that work as independent machines but they run using the resources of your laptop or desktop.

This is what I use when developing with SharePoint.

There are plenty of blog articles about how to build your environment but here are some links to help you get started:-

Microsoft Windows 8 Hyper V Virtualisation Technology
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh857623.aspx

VMWare Workstation Virtualisation Technology
https://vmware.com/products/ws/

Virtual Box Virtualisation Technology
https://www.virtualbox.org/

Video on how to build SharePoint 2010 Virtual Machine:
https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/SharePointSideshow/Setting-Up-a-SharePoint-Developer-Virtual-Machine

Comment: Thank you! The problem why I can't install SharePoint on my local computer is related to hardware requirements. Unfortunately Virtualisation technology can't solve this problem. Anyway thanks I'm very interested in such technologies.

Comment: Ah I see, I would try and see what you can do to resolve this. SharePoint Development can get frustrating enough when are able to debug locally, let alone what it would be like debugging remotely ;)