# How to fix “A SharePoint server is not installed on this computer” in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, sharepoint-server

I'm trying to develop a Visual WebPart using Visual Studio 2010. I have not installed SharePoint 2013 locally on my developer pc, but I have installed it on my Windows 2008 Server.

When I try to create a new project I get this message:

"A SharePoint server is not installed on this computer. A SharePoint server must be installed to work with SharePoint projects."

I have try following link and not solved my problem.

http://sharepointcustomization.blogspot.in/2012/10/sharepoint-server-is-not-installed-on.html

http://www.jbmurphy.com/2012/02/09/how-to-use-visual-studio-to-package-a-sharepoint-solution-if-you-dont-have-sharepoint-installed/

Comment: Hi, what is the reason not to have SP installed on the developer machine? If the reason is that it has only Windows 7 installed, you can use Virtual Machine with SP installed there (Hyper-V) for development.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you need to have SP2013 installed on the same machine to be able to do most of the SP2013 development tasks ([SharePoint 2013 apps is an exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj220047.aspx)). Most likely there is no workarounds for that.

**UPDATE1:** I have [found a question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/59065/how-visual-studio-checkes-that-sharepoint-has-been-installed-on-my-local-pc), which shows how to make Visual Studio think that SP is installed. However, anyway, even if it works in your case, I don't think it is a good idea to just trick Visual Studio that SP is installed, but it seems there is no good workarounds for that. Development for SP is rather hard and it will be a pain to constantly redeploy a solution on the remote server and it is very hard to debug it in such a case.